# Xml loading from memory stream issue

Tags: c#, .net, xml, stream

Here is my code:

```
MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlStream);

//Add some elements and attributes.

xmlWriter.WriterEndDocument();
xmlWriter.Flush();
xmlWriter.Close();
```

Ok, now that I've closed the XmlWriter is there any way to access the XmlStream again?

If I don't close then when I want to use xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream) it gives an exception that says "Root Element is missing"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't close the stream you can set the Position property to 0 to go back to the start and then create an XmlReader to read the stream back or use XmlDocument.Load as you're trying to do.

To summarise, remove xmlWriter.Close() and then call xmlStream.Position = 0, then call xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream)

Comment: Thanks for responding, It throws an exception that says "Root Element is missing"

Comment: You'll get that on your original code because the position of the stream is at the end (plus above you're also closing it), so there's nothing for the reader to read. As long as your code has output valid XML, setting the position back to 0 without closing the stream (should still flush) and reading back from the stream will work fine. I do this often.

Answer (score 4):

Not as a stream - but you can get at the data.

[`MemoryStream.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) works even after you've closed it.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your answer. As I'm quite new in programming, It's unclear to me. I would like to know if I'm able the to load it back in a xmlDoc even if its converted to array? Will serialization be of any help here?

Comment: @Kourosh: You can create a new (open) `MemoryStream` wrapping the same data as the old one: `Stream newStream = new MemoryStream(oldStream.ToArray());` - but another alternative is simply not to close the stream, of course.

Comment: Yep, it works fine Jon, however as you mentioned just realized there's no need to close the writer so no need to create a new stream. thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you want to access the underlying stream further, you shouldn't close the XmlWriter since closing it actually means closing the underlying stream. You can dispose of the stream after you're done with it using:

```
xmlStream.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't access disposed (closed) object (stream) anymore.